# How to know if a transaction (tx) succeed or failed after awaitTxConfirmed?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

How to know if a transaction (tx) succeed or fail after `awaitTxConfirmed`? Is there any function to get a tx on-chain by `TxId`?

Answer (score 4):

`awaitTxConfirmed` is actually part of the off-chain code, so your computer is checking the chain to see if the transaction has become part of the ledger.

Sadly, right now `awaitTxConfirmed` does not know that a transaction has failed and if it did fail, your smart contact would be blocked, unless you introduce a logic to time out if your transaction is not included in the ledger for some amount of blocks for example.

However, I know the plutus team is working to solve this and we might have this functionality soon in Plutus.